Large white area on screen on MacBook Pro 2015 laptop running Ubuntu 24.04
I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 on a MacBook Pro 2015 15" retina laptop (model 11,5) with Intel HD graphics, and it's showing a large white area that covers most of the desktop.

The install was set to use all available drivers, including proprietary ones.
The artifact persists when changing the screen resolution, though the aspect ratio of the area may vary and even take up the entire screen.
Some windows, such as the Settings, are displayed correctly.

Others, such as the terminal, also show white artifacts.

Would you know how to solve or debug this?
EDIT: I tried the suggestions from St Joseph University's answer and they did not work. However, looking at kernel logs (sudo dmesg) I found a number of errors reading:
... DMAR: DRHD: handling fault status reg 3
... DMAR: [DMA Read] Request device ... non-zero reserved fields in PTE

I found posts suggesting to add intel_iommu=igfx_off to the GRUB config in case of DMA errors, and that seems to have done the trick. I'll call it a victory even if I didn't get down to the root cause of this.
For reference, the full fix is:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
# Add intel_iommu=igfx_off to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT list
sudo update-grub


Please add the fix part as an answer below (you can post your own answer), and remove that part from the question.

igfx_off worked for me as well. 2015 macbook, ubuntu 24.04.

Questionaire's answer above works, thanks.
Execute sudo nano /etc/default/grub and add
intel_iommu=igfx_off 

to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT list. After that, execute
sudo update-grub


To fix a large white area on your MacBook Pro 2015 running Ubuntu 24.04, try updating graphics drivers and adding the nomodeset or i915.modeset=1 kernel parameter in the GRUB configuration, then update GRUB and reboot.
