Desktop screen is white and graphics are not loading properly on Ubuntu 22.04.4
I am currently on a 2015 Macbook Pro with AMD graphics and an Intel i7. I think this has occurred after an update, but I am not sure.
The login screen is totally fine. The issue occurs when it loads into the desktop. I am met with a blank white screen instead of the usual desktop background. I have to highlight text for it to show.
Has anyone encountered this issue a well? Is there a fix?

Try this it worked for me - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1514609/large-white-area-on-screen-on-macbook-pro-2015-laptop-running-ubuntu-24-04

Can confirm, this worked for me as well. Sorry, forgot to update this post.
